# cannot get apache2 redirect working for a site

Tags: apache-2.2

what i want to do is to redirect all visitors going to example.com to www.example.com.it seems a very common task but for some reason it is not working for this specific site .it always points to the default one. And strangely, if i replace the domain with another one(yyyyy.com and www.yyyyy.com), it works all right.i check my DNS,and it's resolved to the right IP.

here's my virtual host configure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
 Servername www.example.com

 <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   Servername example.com
   Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

this is the output of wget -S http://example.com

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 07:11:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 06 May 2014 16:10:43 GMT
ETag: "222c32-b1-4f8bd7d6326c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 177
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about it not working? Do you get redirected to the wrong site? Not redirected at all? Can you show output from using wget or curl to request http://example.com/ ?

Comment: agree with @Andrew some more information would be helpful to give an informed answer.

Comment: @Andrew,i guest it doesn't redirect at all. it just show apache2's default page. but by just changing domain name, everything will work all right. i don't know what've gone wrong

Comment: @benson: Can you include the output from using `wget -S http://example.com` ? This will show the server response and help diagnose whether the 301 is being generated.

Comment: @Andrew,i've added the output of wget -S

Comment: Do you have a `NameVirtualHost` directive somewhere?

Comment: Do you have mod_alias enabled?

Comment: yes! it's weird that this issue only happens to this single domain. if i replace it with another domain, it work expected! could it be related .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

To get `VirtualHost` with `ServerName` working you need to enable `NameVirtualHost`. Make sure you have this line in your config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```